# Excel macro only runs on some machines - possible Array Issue?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm building a macro which is to do the following steps -

1. Read folder names in a specific location
2. Use the names to vlookup with a database
3. Combine those details to rename and save elsewhere

When I run it on my own computer, it runs great, but on my partner's computer, I get a Type Mismatch Error 13 on the first line of the For/Next loop at the bottom

Abridged code is below (think I cleared out all the unnecessary items)

'''

```
    Dim xWb As Workbook, xWbLoading As Workbook
    Dim xWs As Worksheet, xWsLoading As Worksheet, xWsLoading2 As Worksheet
    Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Variant, arr3() As Variant
    Dim last_row As Long, last_row_loading As Long, j As Long


Set xWbLoading = Workbooks("YTN Loading")
Set xWsLoading = xWbLoading.Sheets("FCL")

Set xWb = Workbooks("Macro Book")
Set xWs = xWb.Sheets("SI Upload")       

last_row = xWs.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
last_row_loading = xWsLoading.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

arr1 = xWs.Range("B3:B" & last_row)
arr2 = xWsLoading.Range("D2:Q" & last_row_loading).Value

ReDim arr3(1 To UBound(arr1), 1 To 2)

For i = 1 To last_row-2
**arr3(i, 1) = Application.VLookup(arr1(i, 1), arr2, 14, False)** 'error here
arr3(i, 2) = Application.VLookup(arr1(i, 1), arr2, 8, False)


xWs.Range("C" & i + 2).Value = Left(arr3(i, 1), 7)
xWs.Range("A" & i + 2).Value = xWs.Range("B" & i + 2).Value & " " & arr3(i, 2)
Next i
```

When I run this on my machine, it runs great. However, when I pass it on to the user who will use the code, it fails at the Array section.

Some troubleshooting so far -
Arr1 is string, Arr2 includes multiple data types, 
Arr3 will pull back both a date an a string.

Reading some solutions, seems this may have been an issue - Array not able to handle multiple types. But I'm not sure as I am able to get the right information when I run it.

Information about the machines:
Both run the same system language / excel 2016 (the working machine is o365 / non-working machine is regular excel 2016).

Is there any solution here, or do I need to rebuild the vLookup section? And if so - any suggestions for the ideal way to build this - not sure if there's a better way to handle than Worksheet Function

Comment: Every solution start with knowing where the problem is. Please tell us on which line of your code the error occurs.

Comment: Seems unrelated but you should always include the file extension when accessing workbooks by name: if you don't, the code will fail if the user has unchecked the "hide extensions for known file types" option in Windows Explorer.

Comment: Also you're picking up `arr1` starting from row3, not row1, so it will not have `last_row` as the upper bound of the "row" dimension...  Eg. if `arr1 = Range("B6:B10")` then it will be dimensioned as (1 to 5, 1 to 1)  Difficult to see why that part doesn't fail with an "index out of bounds" error

Comment: Thanks Tim - not sure how I missed '-2' when I copied the code across, but the bounds are corrected (i think). Will definitely add the file extension

Variatus, saw your reply below, but made more obvious in the message where the error is, thank you

Comment: @Tim Williams Interesting point. I didn't know one can omit the extension. - Ohh Microsoft! Making things ever more foolproof until only fools can find their way through the rules :-)

Answer (score 0):

Arr1 is an array. And it's a variant. `arr1 = xWs.Range("B3:B" & last_row)` assigns a range to it. If you want to assign the Value of a range to a variant you would use `

```
Dim arr1 As Variant
arr1 = xWs.Range("B3:B" & last_row).Value
```

But your Dim statement makes arr1 an array of variants. And you don't specify that you want to assign the Value to it. Either of these mistakes would suffice to create a Type Mismatch error. The interesting part is really why and how your computer can manage to still produce a result you like from this code. I presume it must be a version issue. Your mistake is a rather common one and perhaps Excel's VBA applied some clever AI to learn how to correctly guess at what kind of errors you would expect it to deal with :-)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed reply! I think I'm following - step 1 remove '()' from the Dim of Arr1, and step 2 = add '.value' when setting arr1. However, I'm still hitting the same issue of mismatch in the same location. Not sure this is because arr2 is a combination of info, so holds Variant/String & Variant/Date?

Comment: When you assign the values of a range of cells to a variant it can't be already structured, like `Arr()`. Your assignment to `arr2` is correct. Are there any more problems in your code? On which line, please?

Comment: With arr1 now showing:

Dim arr1() As Variant (or Dim arr1 as variant - tried both) & 
arr1 = xWs.Range("B3:B" & last_row).value

I'm still hitting the same error in the same place

Comment: Which place? Am I missing something here?